# Search through the values of all variables in Emacs

Tags: regular-expressions, search, variables

I'd like to find which variables contain a certain value.

Is there a way to do a regex search through the values of every variable in Emacs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Does `apropos-value` do what you're looking for?

```
(apropos-value PATTERN &optional DO-ALL)

Show all symbols whose value’s printed representation matches PATTERN.
PATTERN can be a word, a list of words (separated by spaces),
or a regexp (using some regexp special characters).  If it is a word,
search for matches for that word as a substring.  If it is a list of words,
search for matches for any two (or more) of those words.
```

Answer (score 3):

[Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) command **`icicle-apropos-value`** enhances vanilla command `apropos-value`, by letting you simultaneously match the variable ***name*** and ***value*** against regexps (or substrings or other patterns).  You *need* not match them both, but you can match them both.

And (as with all Icicles completion) you can match the name or the value or both *progressively*, that is, using multiple patterns incrementally. This is particularly important for a case where, as you say, you are matching against all variables in Emacs, to start with. That is, you do *not* care to match against names; you just want to match values.

To match both name and value just use **`C-M-j`** to end the name pattern and begin the value pattern. So to match only values, you start with `C-M-j` and then type the value pattern, as the name pattern is empty.

For example, to see all variables whose current value matches `nil` (`S-TAB` shows matches):

`M-x icicle-apropos-value RET`

**`SYMBOL C-M-j VALUE:`** `C-M-j` **`nil`** `S-TAB`

To see all variables whose current value matches regexp `.*plist`:

**`SYMBOL C-M-j VALUE:`** `C-M-j` **`.*plist`** `S-TAB`

Matching variables and their values are shown in buffer `*Completions*`, as completion candidates.  You can cycle among the candidates, making each one current in turn, using the vertical-arrow keys: `<down> <down> <down>...`.

The *first doc-string line* for the current completion candidate is shown in the mode-line of `*Completions*`.

You can get a *full* (i.e., `C-h v`) description of the current candidate by using a help key on it: `C-M-mouse-2` or `C-M-RET`. To see help on each candidate in turn, cycle using arrow keys with `C-M-` (e.g., repeat `C-M-<down>`).

See [Value-Aware Variable-Apropos Multi-Commands](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_A_Propos_d'Apropos#Value-AwareVariable-AproposMulti-Commands).

`C-h f icicle-apropos-value` says this:

> **`icicle-apropos-value`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `icicles-cmd1.el`.
>
> It is bound to `menu-bar help-menu apropos icicles icicle-apropos-value`, `menu-bar help-menu apropos apropos-var-value`,
>   `menu-bar help-menu search-documentation find-option-by-value`.
>
> `(icicle-apropos-value)`
>
> Choose a variable, function, or other symbol description.
>
> This is similar to vanilla command `apropos-value`, but you can match
>   against the variable name and its printed value at the same time.
>
> By default, each completion candidate is [multi-completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Completions) composed of
>   a variable name plus its value.  They are separated by
>   `icicle-list-join-string` (`"^G^J"`, by default).
>
> With a prefix arg, candidates are different kinds of symbols:
>
> - < 0: *functions* and their defs (but byte-compiled defs are skipped)
> - > 0: *symbols* and their plists
> - = 0: *variables* and their values, *functions* and their definitions, and
>      other *symbols* and their plists
> - plain (`C-u`): use the last-computed (*cached*) set of candidates
>
> You can use **`C-$`** during completion to toggle filtering the domain of
>   initial candidates according to the prefix argument, as follows:
>
> - none: only *user options* (+ values)
> - < 0: only *commands* (+ definitions)
> - > 0: only *faces* (+ plists)
> - = 0: only *options* (+ values), *commands* (+ defs), *faces* (+ plists)
>
> See also:
>
> - `icicle-apropos-vars-w-val-satisfying`,
>     `icicle-describe-vars-w-val-satisfying` - values satisfy a *predicate*
> - `icicle-plist` - similar to this command with positive prefix arg
> - `icicle-vardoc`, `icicle-fundoc`, `icicle-doc` - match name & *doc*
> - `icicle-apropos-options-of-type`, `icicle-describe-option-of-type` -
>     match name & *defcustom type*
>
> Because you will often use this command in contexts that result in
>   many, many completion candidates, the following are turned off by
>   default for this command:
>
> - Icomplete mode.  You can toggle this using `M-i M-#`.
> - Icicles incremental completion.  You can cycle this using `M-i #`.
>
> Read input, then call `icicle-doc-action` to act on it.
>
> Input-candidate completion and cycling are available.  While cycling,
>   these keys with prefix `C-` are active:
>
> `C-mouse-2`, `C-return` - Act on current completion candidate only
>   `C-down`, `C-wheel-down` - Move to next completion candidate and act
>   `C-up`, `C-wheel-up` - Move to previous completion candidate and act
>   `C-next`  - Move to next apropos-completion candidate and act
>   `C-prior` - Move to previous apropos-completion candidate and act
>   `C-end`   - Move to next prefix-completion candidate and act
>   `C-home`  - Move to previous prefix-completion candidate and act
>   `C-!`     - Act on *all* candidates, successively (careful!)
>
> When candidate action and cycling are combined (e.g. `C-next`), user
>   option `icicle-act-before-cycle-flag` determines which occurs first.
>
> With prefix **`C-M-`** instead of `C-`, the same keys (`C-M-mouse-2`,
>   `C-M-RET`, `C-M-down`, and so on) provide *help* about candidates.
>
> Use `mouse-2`, `RET`, or `S-RET` to finally choose a candidate, or
>   `C-g` to quit.